# Heap data structure implementation swift

Tags: swift, data-structures, heap

I have a question about heap data structure.

I have a three public functions. 
I can't make the correct function `shiftUp` and `shiftDown`.

In `shiftUp` I try to compare elements in heap and swap their

This is my code implementation:

```
class Heap {
    var heap: [Int]
    init(array: [Int]) {
        self.heap = array
    }

    var findMax: Int { return heap.first! }

    private var count: Int {return heap.count}

    private func floor() -> Int {
        let floor = log2(Double(heap.count))
        return Int(floor)
    }

    private func indexOf(element: Int) -> Int {
        return heap.index(of: element)!
    }

    private func parentIndex(index: Int) -> Int {
        return floor()*(index-1/2)
    }

    private func leftChildIndex(index: Int) -> Int {
        return 2*index+1
    }

    private func rightChildIndex(index: Int) -> Int {
        return 2*index+2
    }

    private func swapIfNeed(first: Int,second: Int) {
            swap(&heap[indexOf(element: first)] , &heap[indexOf(element: second)])
    }

    func shiftDown(index: Int) {
        let parent = heap[parentIndex(index: index)]
        let leftChild = heap[leftChildIndex(index: index)]
        let rightChild = heap[rightChildIndex(index: index)]
        if parent <= leftChild {
            swapIfNeed(first: parent, second: leftChild)
            shiftDown(index: index+1)
        } else if parent <= rightChild {
            swapIfNeed(first: parent, second: rightChild)
            shiftDown(index: index+1)
        }
    }


    private func shiftUp() {}
    func removeMax() {

    }
    func addElement(element: Int) {}
}
```

Comment: Your question isn't clear. What problem are you asking? And you didn't finish the last sentence: *"I try to compare elements in heap and swap their"*.

Comment: @rmaddy i dnt understand how must work func shiftDown

Comment: what does it do in parentIndex method 'return floor()*(index-1/2)'?

Answer (score 0):

Please find my implementation of Heap DS in Swift 4.

```
struct Heap<T: Comparable>{
private var heap = [T]()

mutating func insert(element: T){
heap.append(element)
var index = heap.count - 1
heapify(childIndex: index)
}

mutating func heapify(childIndex: Int){
    var parentIndex = (childIndex - 1)/2
    if parentIndex >= 0 {
        if heap[parentIndex] < heap[childIndex] {
            var tempElement = heap[parentIndex]
            heap[parentIndex] = heap[childIndex]
            heap[childIndex] = tempElement
            heapify(childIndex: parentIndex)
        }else{
            print("Created valid heap")
        }
    }else{
        print("No parent")
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Details

- Swift 5.2, Xcode 11.4 (11E146)

### Solution

```
import Foundation

struct Heap<Element> where Element: Comparable {
    // elements - collection where heap store values
    private(set) var elements = [Element]()
    // priority - description of order in a heap
    let priority: Priority
    init(priority: Priority) { self.priority = priority }

    enum Priority {
        case parentsGreaterThanOrEqualChildren
        case parentsLessThanOrEqualChildren

        func isCorrect(parentValue: Element, childValue: Element) -> Bool {
            switch self {
                case .parentsGreaterThanOrEqualChildren: return parentValue >= childValue
                case .parentsLessThanOrEqualChildren: return parentValue <= childValue
            }
        }
    }
}

// MARK: Init

extension Heap {

    // Init heap from representing array means that array is already ordered to be as base of heap.
    // If not - heap will be not created
    init?(fromRepresenting array: [Element], priority: Priority) {
        self.init(priority: priority)
        elements = array
        if array.count > 1 {
            var index: Int!
            var indicesQueue = [0]
            indicesQueue.reserveCapacity(indicesQueue.count/2)
            while !indicesQueue.isEmpty {
                index = indicesQueue.popLast()
                let childrenIndices = self.childrenIndices(ofParentAt: index)
                if let childIndex = childrenIndices.left {
                    guard isPriorityCorrect(parentIndex: index, childIndex: childIndex) else { return nil }
                    indicesQueue.insert(childIndex, at: 0)
                }
                if let childIndex = childrenIndices.right {
                    guard isPriorityCorrect(parentIndex: index, childIndex: childIndex) else { return nil }
                    indicesQueue.insert(childIndex, at: 0)
                }
            }
            index += 1
        }
    }

    // Init heap by inserting elements from array means that elements in array will be reordered if needed
    init(insertElementsFrom array: [Element], priority: Priority) {
        self.init(priority: priority)
        if array.isEmpty { return }
        elements = array
        for index in stride(from: count/2, through: 0, by: -1) {
            siftDown(startAt: index)
        }
    }

    // Check if the priority of the parent element higher than child element
    private func isPriorityCorrect (parentIndex: Int, childIndex: Int) -> Bool {
        priority.isCorrect(parentValue: elements[parentIndex], childValue: elements[childIndex])
    }

    private func isPriorityCorrect (parentValue: Element, childValue: Element) -> Bool {
        priority.isCorrect(parentValue: parentValue, childValue: childValue)
    }
}

// MARK: States

extension Heap {
    // Get flag that heap is empty (has no values)
    var isEmpty: Bool { elements.isEmpty }
     // Get number of elements in heap
    var count: Int { elements.count }
     // Show element with max priority (first that will be removed)
    func peek() -> Element? { elements.first }
}

// MARK: Get index

extension Heap {
    // calculated property returns value(s) that do not check bounds of existing heap's collection (elements)
    private func calculateParentIndex(childAt index: Int) -> Int { (index - 1) / 2 }
    private func calculateChildrenIndices(ofParentAt index: Int) -> (left: Int, right: Int)  {
        let left = index * 2 + 1
        return (left, left + 1)
    }

    // Check if range 0..<elements.count contains index
    private func isValid(index: Int) -> Bool { 0 ..< count ~= index }

    // Get parent's left and right indices. left and left indices can be nil (do not exist in current heap)
    func childrenIndices(ofParentAt index: Int) -> (left: Int?, right: Int?) {
        let indices = calculateChildrenIndices(ofParentAt: index)
        return (isValid(index: indices.left) ? indices.left : nil,
                isValid(index: indices.right) ? indices.right : nil)
    }

    // Get the parent index of the child
    func parentIndex(childAt index: Int) -> Int? {
        let index = calculateParentIndex(childAt: index)
        if isValid(index: index) { return index }
        return nil
    }
}

// MARK: Sift - Reordering mechanism.
// Heap order - where each parent node has higher priority than the child nodes.

extension Heap {
    // Traverse binary tree from parent node (index) to each child node.
    // Swap elements if needed to order in heap.
    private mutating func siftDown(startAt index: Int, stopAt count: Int? = nil) {
        let count = count ?? self.count
        var parentIndex = index
        var childrenIndices: (left: Int, right: Int)
        var swapDestinationIndex = index
        while true {
            childrenIndices = self.calculateChildrenIndices(ofParentAt: parentIndex)
            swapDestinationIndex = parentIndex
            if  childrenIndices.left < count &&
                isPriorityCorrect(parentIndex: childrenIndices.left, childIndex: parentIndex) {
                    swapDestinationIndex = childrenIndices.left
            }

            if  childrenIndices.right < count &&
                isPriorityCorrect(parentIndex: childrenIndices.right, childIndex: swapDestinationIndex) {
                    swapDestinationIndex = childrenIndices.right
            }

            guard parentIndex != swapDestinationIndex else { return }
            elements.swapAt(parentIndex, swapDestinationIndex)
            parentIndex = swapDestinationIndex
        }
    }

    // Traverse binary tree from child node (index) to the head node of the tree.
    // Swap elements if needed to order in heap.
    private mutating func siftUp(startAt firstIndex: Int) {
        var child = firstIndex
        var parent = calculateParentIndex(childAt: firstIndex)
        while child > 0 && isPriorityCorrect(parentIndex: child, childIndex: parent) {
            elements.swapAt(child, parent)
            child = parent
            parent = calculateParentIndex(childAt: child)
        }
    }
}

// MARK: Insert/Remove

extension Heap {
    // Insert new element in heap in correct position
    mutating func insert(_ value: Element) {
        elements.append(value)
        siftUp(startAt: count - 1)
    }

    // Remove element with max priority (first in array "elements") and restore order (swap elements) if needed
    @discardableResult
    mutating func removeElementWithHighestPriority() -> Element? {
        switch count {
            case 0: return nil
            case 1: return elements.removeLast()
            default:
                elements.swapAt(0, count - 1)
                defer { siftDown(startAt: 0) }
                return elements.removeLast()
        }
    }

    // Remove element at specific index and restore order (swap elements) if needed
    @discardableResult
    mutating func remove(at index: Int) -> Element?  {
        guard isValid(index: index) else { return nil }
        if index == count - 1 { return elements.removeLast() }
        elements.swapAt(index, count-1)
        defer {
            siftDown(startAt: index)
            siftUp(startAt: index)
        }
        return elements.removeLast()
    }
}

// MARK: Exporting

extension Heap {
    func representAsReversedSortedArray() -> [Element] {
        var heap = self
        for index in heap.elements.indices.reversed() {
            heap.elements.swapAt(0, index)
            heap.siftDown(startAt: 0, stopAt: index)
        }
        return heap.elements
    }
}

// MARK: Search

extension Heap {
    // Get first index of the element
    func firstIndex(of element: Element, startAt index: Int = 0) -> Int? {
        guard   isValid(index: index),
                isPriorityCorrect(parentValue: elements[index], childValue: element) else { return nil }
        if elements[index] == element { return index }
        let childrenIndices = self.calculateChildrenIndices(ofParentAt: index)
        let left = firstIndex(of: element, startAt: childrenIndices.left)
        let right = firstIndex(of: element, startAt: childrenIndices.right)
        if let left = left, let right = right {return min(left, right) }
        return left ?? right
    }
}

// MARK: CustomStringConvertible & Debug info

extension Heap: CustomStringConvertible {
    public var description: String { "\(elements)" }

    // Get binary tree representation of the heap. Helpful for debugging
    func getDiagram() -> String { diagram(forElementAt: 0) }
    private func diagramSpacing() -> String { "  " }
    private func diagram(forElementAt index: Int?,
                         _ top: String = " ",
                         _ root: String = " ",
                         _ bottom: String = " ") -> String {
        guard let index = index else { return "" }
        let childrenIndices = self.childrenIndices(ofParentAt: index)

        if childrenIndices.left == nil && childrenIndices.right == nil {
            return root + " \(elements[index])\n"
        }

        var parentValueString: String!
        if root == " " {
            parentValueString = root + "\(elements[index])\n"
        } else {
            parentValueString = root + " \(elements[index])\n"
        }

        return  diagram(forElementAt: childrenIndices.right,
                        top + "   ",
                        top + "┌─",
                        top + "│  ") +
                parentValueString +
                diagram(forElementAt: childrenIndices.left,
                        bottom + "│  ",
                        bottom + "└─",
                        bottom + "   ")
    }
}
```

### Usage

```
let array = [1, 2,3, 4,6,7,8, 32,44,113]
if let heap = Heap(fromRepresenting: array, priority: .parentsLessThanOrEqualChildren) {
    //...
}

if let heap = Heap(fromRepresenting: array, priority: .parentsGreaterThanOrEqualChildren) {
    //...
}

var heap = Heap<Int>(priority: .parentsLessThanOrEqualChildren)
heap = Heap(priority: .parentsGreaterThanOrEqualChildren)

heap = Heap(insertElementsFrom: array, priority: .parentsLessThanOrEqualChildren)
heap = Heap(insertElementsFrom: array, priority: .parentsGreaterThanOrEqualChildren)

print("elements: \(heap.elements)")
heap.insert(1)
print("remove: \(heap.removeElementWithHighestPriority())")
print("first index of 2: \(heap.firstIndex(of: 2))")
print("is empty: \(heap.isEmpty)")
print("count: \(heap.count)")
print("peek: \(heap.peek())")
print(heap.getDiagram())
```

### Usage logs

```
elements: [113, 44, 8, 32, 6, 7, 3, 1, 4, 2]
remove: Optional(113)
first index of 2: Optional(9)
is empty: false
count: 10
peek: Optional(44)
    ┌─ 3
 ┌─ 8
 │  └─ 7
 44
 │  ┌─ 6
 │  │  └─ 2
 └─ 32
    │  ┌─ 1
    └─ 4
       └─ 1
```

### Unit tests

```
import XCTest
@testable import stackoverflow_39876805

class HeapSpecificTests: XCTestCase {

    func testInit() {
        var array = [8, 6,5, 4,3,2,1]
        XCTAssertEqual(Heap(fromRepresenting: array, priority: .parentsGreaterThanOrEqualChildren)?.elements, array)
        XCTAssertEqual(Heap(fromRepresenting: array, priority: .parentsLessThanOrEqualChildren)?.elements, nil)

        Heap(fromRepresenting: array, priority: .parentsLessThanOrEqualChildren)?.firstIndex(of: 5)

        array = [1, 2,1, 2,1,2,1]
        XCTAssertEqual(Heap(fromRepresenting: array, priority: .parentsGreaterThanOrEqualChildren)?.elements, nil)
        XCTAssertEqual(Heap(fromRepresenting: array, priority: .parentsLessThanOrEqualChildren)?.elements, nil)

        array = [1, 2,3, 4,5,6,7, 8,9,10]
        XCTAssertEqual(Heap(fromRepresenting: array, priority: .parentsLessThanOrEqualChildren)?.elements, array)
        XCTAssertEqual(Heap(fromRepresenting: array, priority: .parentsGreaterThanOrEqualChildren)?.elements, nil)

        array = [1]
        XCTAssertEqual(Heap(fromRepresenting: array, priority: .parentsGreaterThanOrEqualChildren)?.elements, array)
        XCTAssertEqual(Heap(fromRepresenting: array, priority: .parentsLessThanOrEqualChildren)?.elements, array)

        array = []
        XCTAssertEqual(Heap(fromRepresenting: array, priority: .parentsGreaterThanOrEqualChildren)?.elements, array)
        XCTAssertEqual(Heap(fromRepresenting: array, priority: .parentsLessThanOrEqualChildren)?.elements, array)

        array = [1,1,1]
        XCTAssertEqual(Heap(fromRepresenting: array, priority: .parentsGreaterThanOrEqualChildren)?.elements, array)
        XCTAssertEqual(Heap(fromRepresenting: array, priority: .parentsLessThanOrEqualChildren)?.elements, array)

        array = [1,2]
        XCTAssertEqual(Heap(fromRepresenting: array, priority: .parentsLessThanOrEqualChildren)?.elements, array)
        XCTAssertEqual(Heap(fromRepresenting: array, priority: .parentsGreaterThanOrEqualChildren)?.elements, nil)
    }
}


class HeapTests1: XCTestCase {
    typealias Element = Int
    typealias Collection = [Element]
    func createDataForTest() -> Collection { [8, 6,5, 4,3,2,1] }
    func createHeapsForTest() -> [Heap<Element>] {
        let data = createDataForTest()
        return [.init(insertElementsFrom: data, priority: .parentsLessThanOrEqualChildren),
                .init(insertElementsFrom: data, priority: .parentsGreaterThanOrEqualChildren)]
    }

    func testInit() {
        var dataForTest = createDataForTest()
        var sortedDataForTest = dataForTest.sorted()
        _testInit(dataForTest: &dataForTest,
                  sortedDataForTest: &sortedDataForTest,
                  priority: .parentsGreaterThanOrEqualChildren, sort: >=)

        _testInit(dataForTest: &dataForTest,
                  sortedDataForTest: &sortedDataForTest,
                  priority: .parentsLessThanOrEqualChildren, sort: <=)
    }

    func testRemove() { for heap in createHeapsForTest() { assertValid(heap: heap) } }
    func testRemoveAtIndex() {
        var heaps = createHeapsForTest()
        var tempArray: Collection
        var indexToRemove: Int!
        for index in 0..<heaps.count {
            while !heaps[index].isEmpty {
                tempArray = heaps[index].elements
                indexToRemove = (0..<tempArray.count).randomElement() ?? 0
                XCTAssertEqual(tempArray.remove(at: indexToRemove), heaps[index].remove(at: indexToRemove))
                XCTAssertEqual(tempArray.count, heaps[index].count)
                assertValid(heap: heaps[index])
            }
            XCTAssertTrue(heaps[index].isEmpty)
        }
    }

    func testSort() {
        for heap in createHeapsForTest() {
            switch heap.priority {
            case .parentsGreaterThanOrEqualChildren:
                XCTAssertEqual(heap.elements.sorted(by: <=), heap.representAsReversedSortedArray())
            case .parentsLessThanOrEqualChildren:
                XCTAssertEqual(heap.elements.sorted(by: >=), heap.representAsReversedSortedArray())
            }
        }
    }

    func testInsert() {
        let dataForTest = createDataForTest()
        var sortedArray: Collection!
        var sortedHeapElements: Collection!
        var heaps = createHeapsForTest()
        for i in 0..<heaps.count {
            sortedArray = (heaps[i].elements + dataForTest).sorted()
            dataForTest.forEach { heaps[i].insert($0) }
            sortedHeapElements = heaps[i].elements.sorted()
            XCTAssertEqual(sortedHeapElements, sortedArray)
            XCTAssertEqual(heaps[i].count, sortedArray.count)
            XCTAssertEqual(heaps[i].isEmpty, sortedArray.isEmpty)
            assertValid(heap: heaps[i])
            switch heaps[i].priority {
                case .parentsGreaterThanOrEqualChildren: XCTAssertEqual(heaps[i].peek(), sortedHeapElements.max())
                case .parentsLessThanOrEqualChildren: XCTAssertEqual(heaps[i].peek(), sortedHeapElements.min())
            }
        }
    }

    func testSearchAt() {
        var heapElements: Collection!
        var sortedHeapElements: Collection!
        for heap in createHeapsForTest() {
            heapElements = heap.elements
            sortedHeapElements = heapElements.sorted()
            for element in sortedHeapElements {
                XCTAssertEqual(heap.firstIndex(of: element), heapElements.firstIndex(of: element))
            }
        }
    }

    private func _testInit(dataForTest: inout Collection,
                           sortedDataForTest: inout Collection,
                           priority: Heap<Element>.Priority,
                           sort: ((Element, Element) -> Bool)?) {
        var heap = Heap(insertElementsFrom: dataForTest, priority: priority)
        XCTAssertEqual(heap.elements.sorted(), sortedDataForTest)
        assertValid(heap: heap, sort: sort)

        heap = Heap(priority: priority)
        dataForTest.forEach { heap.insert($0) }
        XCTAssertEqual(heap.elements.sorted(), sortedDataForTest)
        assertValid(heap: heap, sort: sort)
    }

    private func assertValid<Element>(heap: Heap<Element>, sort: ((Element, Element) -> Bool)? = nil) {
        var heap = heap
        var currentElement: Element?
        var previousElement = heap.removeElementWithHighestPriority()
        var elementWithMaxPriority: Element!
        while !heap.isEmpty {
            XCTAssertEqual(heap.isEmpty, false)
            XCTAssertGreaterThanOrEqual(heap.count, 1)
            switch heap.priority {
                case .parentsGreaterThanOrEqualChildren: elementWithMaxPriority = heap.elements.max()
                case .parentsLessThanOrEqualChildren: elementWithMaxPriority = heap.elements.min()
            }
            currentElement = heap.removeElementWithHighestPriority()
            XCTAssertEqual(elementWithMaxPriority, currentElement)
            if let sort = sort {
                XCTAssertTrue(sort(previousElement!, currentElement!))
            } else {
                switch heap.priority {
                    case .parentsGreaterThanOrEqualChildren: XCTAssertGreaterThanOrEqual(previousElement!, currentElement!)
                    case .parentsLessThanOrEqualChildren: XCTAssertLessThanOrEqual(previousElement!, currentElement!)
                }
            }
            previousElement = currentElement
        }
        XCTAssertEqual(heap.isEmpty, true)
    }
}

class HeapTests2: HeapTests1 {
    override func createDataForTest() -> Collection { [1, 2,1, 2,1,2,1] }
}

class HeapTests3: HeapTests1 {
    override func createDataForTest() -> Collection { [1,2] }
    override func createHeapsForTest() -> [Heap<Element>] {
        let data = createDataForTest()
        return super.createHeapsForTest() + [Heap(fromRepresenting: data, priority: .parentsLessThanOrEqualChildren)!]
    }
}

class HeapTests4: HeapTests3 {
    override func createDataForTest() -> Collection { [] }
    override func createHeapsForTest() -> [Heap<Element>] {
        let data = createDataForTest()
        return super.createHeapsForTest() + [Heap(fromRepresenting: data, priority: .parentsGreaterThanOrEqualChildren)!]
    }
}

class HeapTests5: HeapTests3 {
    override func createDataForTest() -> Collection { [1] }
}

class HeapTests6: HeapTests3 {
    override func createDataForTest() -> Collection { [1,1,1] }
}

class HeapTests7: HeapTests1 {
    override func createDataForTest() -> Collection { [1, 20,3, 11,1,44,5, 7,33,45,21,44,41,31,0] }
}
```

### Sources

> Some ideas were taken from Swift Algorithm Club.

- [Swift Algorithm Club. Heap](https://github.com/raywenderlich/swift-algorithm-club/tree/master/Heap)
- [Swift Algorithm Club. Heap sort](https://github.com/raywenderlich/swift-algorithm-club/tree/master/Heap%20Sort)